# Node.js - How to Backup Variables to a file and reobtain it on server relaunch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I think the title says it all. But I want to explain further.

Let's say, I have a running nodejs server which contains a variable that will contain
(almost) all data that the server will store. If I want to do a server restart (due to
some reasons), how do I backup the variables so that it's safe to close the nodejs server,
and to relaunch it with the variables that contains the data when I closed it?

Regards,
JoshuaLangit123

Comment: what do you mean by  backup? Can't you use any db or filesystem file to store & retrieve back on restart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some pseudo code to achieve what you want to do:

1. At startup, read data.json and assign the value of it to your single data variable:

   ```
   var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('data.json'));
   ```
2. When the app is closed using Ctrl-C you can use this handler to write the single data variable back to data.json.

   ```
   process.on( 'SIGINT', function() {
     fs.writeFileSync('data.json', JSON.stringify(data));
     process.exit();
   })
   ```

Comment: This is a nice answer. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on so many things. Usually what you do is use a database (mongodb, mysql, whatever) to store application state.. Users, session, etc

If you **really** do want to dump all the variables to a file that can be read/written to (which I think sounds like a really, really, really bad idea, but hard to know for sure unless I knew what you were doing) you could make a single object that you put all the variables into, which you can json-ify and write to disk.

and then you read that file again (or require it even) when the node instance is started again.